# Shell script programming for gimp

Tags: shell, gimp

I want to run this gimp batch command on terminal

```
gimp -i -b '(batch-despeckle "check.jpg" "out.jpg" 10 3 -1 255)' -b '(gimp-quit 0)'
```

I wrote a shell script for this so that I can reuse the command with different parameters

```
#!/bin/bash
filename_src=$1
filename_dest=$2
radius=$3
type=$4
black=$5
white=$6
gimp -i -b '(batch-despeckle \"$filename_src\" \"$filename_dest\" $radius $type $black $white)' -b '(gimp-quit 0)'
```

I call this script using the command

```
./gimp_despeckle check.jpg out.jpg 10 3 -1 255
```

When I directly run the command , it works but when I run the shell script, it fails. This baffles me. Any ideas.

Comment: What is the purpose of this snippet ?

Comment: A quick way to debug batch commands with parameters is to put "echo" at the beginning of the command (`echo gimp -i -b ...`). This will display the resulting command without running it (useful if you're not sure if the command is formatted correctly).`

Comment: Yes, or use `#!/bin/bash -x`

Answer (score 3):

In shell, you can't surround a string with variables with single quotes : the variable will be not interpolated, so :

```
#!/bin/bash
filename_src="$1"
filename_dest="$2"
radius="$3"
type="$4"
black="$5"
white="$6"
gimp -i -b "(batch-despeckle \"$filename_src\" \"$filename_dest\" $radius $type $black $white)" -b '(gimp-quit 0)'
```

Learn the difference between quotes. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes and http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words